# multi Elements to multi rows

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I made some try with XML Reader, Xpath... and know linq
But wont find a way to solve these things.

I have to extract the information, for each Order into one row, in this row should be the Information of the first elements and the Items and the orders as well as the status of the Orders...

Is there a way to extract all these information to one row within one linq-query? Or do I have to build steps for this?

(Visualstudio 2010/2013 C# .Net 4)

```
<Account>
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <InId>100</InId>
    <CustomID>100000087</CustomID>
    <ZipCode>zipcode</ZipCode>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemID>700</ItemID>
            <ItemName>Itemname1</ItemName>
            <Orders>
                <Order>
                    <IDIndex>1000</IDIndex>
                    <IDParam>T1</IDParam>
                    <Themes>
                        <Theme>
                            <Status>Alert</Status>
                            <Lastget>01.01.2015</Lastget>
                        </Theme>
                    </Themes>
                </Order>
            </Orders>
            <Item>
            <ItemID>800</ItemID>
            <ItemName>Itemname2</ItemName>
            <Orders>
                <Order>
                    <IDIndex>5001</IDIndex>
                    <IDParam>T1</IDParam>
                    <Themes>
                        <Theme>
                            <Status>Alert1</Status>
                            <Lastget>01.01.2015</Lastget>
                        </Theme>
                    </Themes>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                    <IDIndex>5002</IDIndex>
                    <IDParam>T1</IDParam>
                    <Themes>
                        <Theme>
                            <Status>Alert1</Status>
                            <Lastget>01.01.2015</Lastget>
                        </Theme>
                    </Themes>
                </Order>
                <Order>
                    <IDIndex>5003</IDIndex>
                    <IDParam>T1</IDParam>
                    <Themes>
                        <Theme>
                            <Status>Alert2</Status>
                            <Lastget>01.01.2015</Lastget>
                        </Theme>
                    </Themes>
                </Order>
            </Orders>
        </Item>
    </Items>
    </Account>
```

Comment: Surely there is, how you want that information to be presented? Also worth to show what have you tried. Also your xml is missing something..

Comment: I see your xml, but it would be nice to see what you expect the end result to look like. This makes it easier for people trying to answer the question model what you are looking for.

Comment: OK the Result should be  Name, InID, CustomID,ItemID,ItemName,IDIndex,IDParam,Status,Lastget and this for each Order...

Comment: The result will be presented first into a Listbox, but the result have to be stored in a different DB(external)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will give you the required data:-

```
var result = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Item")
                 .Select(x => new
          {
             Name = (string)x.Document.Root.Element("Name"),
             InId = (string)x.Document.Root.Element("InId"),
             CustomID = (string)x.Document.Root.Element("CustomID"),
             ItemID = (string)x.Element("ItemID"),
             ItemName = (string)x.Element("ItemName"),
             OrdersList = x.Descendants("Order")
                           .Select(y => new
                              {
                                 IDIndex = (string)y.Element("IDIndex"),
                                 IDParam = (string)y.Element("IDParam"),
                                 ThemesList = y.Descendants("Theme")
                                               .Select(z => new 
                                              {
                                                 Status = (string)z.Element("Status"),
                                                 Lastget = (string)z.Element("Lastget")
                                              }).ToList()
                               }).ToList()
         });
```

Please note that two lists will be created for 2 `items`, and for each item I am creating a list of `orders` and within each order list of `themes`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get a result. I get a Result.count in my example of 43 in my xml example posted that equals 4. while I'm new at this point I have to exam the lists...

Comment: So yes i made some test and the loop through the themes list is my perfect result!!! Thankx